# Constant value updating in MySql table in Php without actual values

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my code. When I print mobile number using echo it shows correct one , but on checking mysql table after insert query, I dont see mobile number, but mobile number in database is updated with 2147483647

```
 <?php
    include 'db_connect.php';    
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
        header("location:main_login.php");

    $client_name=$_POST['name']; 
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pan=$_POST['pan'];
    $tan=$_POST['tan'];
    echo $mobile;
    $sql="INSERT INTO client (Name,Address,mobile,Email,PAN,Tan) VALUES ('$client_name','$address','$mobile','$email','$pan','$tan')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if($result==1){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Client added successfully")';
    echo '</script>';

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Use VARCHAR datatypes for Phone numbers in a database, not short 32-bit integer values

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use in database Integer type, which allow to store data in interval [-2147483648 -> 2147483647](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). But your telephone number biggest than 2147483647 and Mysql cuts it to 2147483647. Try to use varchar instead of integer.